# Compiling and building is very slow on every IDE

Tags: visual-studio, netbeans, ide, codeblocks

After installing Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, everything got messy, compiling is very slow (it takes 30 seconds to compile even hello world). My last post was that compiling in NetBeans is very slow, but after installing and building a project in CodeBlocks, I see that every IDE has the same issue.

What to do? I deleted everything in %temp%, all junk files, all unused registries and problem still persists.

Comment: Hard to say... Try using Process Explorer and Process Monitor to see which process is taking all your Disk IO or CPU (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533). Trying to disable or updating Anti-Virus may also be a thing to try.

Comment: It seems that "Avast!" antivirus was slowing down everything. Thanks!